# Why does "missing" mean when I look at the revision history of a Cloudant document

Tags: ibm-cloud, couchdb, cloudant

When I try to see the revision history of a document in Cloudant using the `/<DB>/<doc_id>?revs_info=true` call I get the following:

```
"_revs_info": [
{
"rev": "4-xxx",
"status": "available"
},
{
"rev": "3-xxx",
"status": "missing"
},
{
"rev": "2-xxx",
"status": "missing"
},
{
"rev": "1-xxx",
"status": "missing"
}
```

What does `status:missing` mean?

Answer (score 2):

In Cloudant, old revisions are regularly purged using a process called compaction, which is designed to manage the size of your database.
Once a revision of a document is superseded, it eventually gets compacted by a background task. Once that happens, the revision's content is no longer available and you get the `missing` status message.

Because compaction works in the background asynchronously, you should not think of or use revisions as a way of accessing old versions of documents because it will let you down!

There is more information about revisions in [this blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2018/05/22/Cloudant-Fundamentals-3.html#can-i-use-the-revsion-tree-as-a-version-control-system-for-my-documents)